# Corda General SSL exception due to Signature not match

Tags: corda

I am trying to deploy Corda nodes to network with dynamic network map. Besides, implementing the network map endpoints, there's separate endpoint to build certificates using X509Utilities which I manually copy to Corda certificate directory. However, during node startup, I am getting handshake error due to General SSL exception with Signature not match.

Repository Url: https://github.com/ashubisht/spring-boot-network-map/tree/utkarsh_sbmp_master

The endpoints are implemented in src/main/kotlin/io/nmap/controller/
Certificate service is implemented in https://github.com/ashubisht/spring-boot-network-map/blob/utkarsh_sbmp_master/src/main/kotlin/io/nmap/service/certificate/CertificateService.kt

What can be done to resolve this issue.

Node.conf configuration file

```
myLegalName : "CN=Notary Service,O=NmapSrv.io,L=Chandigarh,C=IN"
keyStorePassword : "password"
trustStorePassword : "password"
p2pAddress : "localhost:12345"
rpcSettings = {
    useSsl = false
    standAloneBroker = false
    address : "localhost:10003"
    adminAddress : "localhost:10004"
}
webAddress : "localhost:12347"
notary : {
    validating : true
}
devMode : false
compatibilityZoneURL : "http://localhost:7080"
```

UPDATE: Error Logs URL: https://pastebin.com/KeLf46m6

Comment: Please update the question with the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Hi Joel. Added pastebin error logs url at last ( https://pastebin.com/KeLf46m6 )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to build the network yourself from the scratch. We actually don't suggest that. There is multiple Corda network tool for you to use out of the box.

1. Network Bootstrapper:
   https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/network-bootstrapper.html#network-bootstrapper
2. Corda Enterprise Network Manager:
   https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.5/operations/deployment/cenm-deployment.html